# Vectorizing matrix operations using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I wrote the code below that uses a for loop. I would like to ask if there is a way to vectorize the operation within the second for loop since I intend to work with larger matrices.

```
import numpy as np

num = 5

A = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5], [4,5,6,4,5], [7,8,9,4,5], [10,11,12,4,5], [13,14,15,4,5]])
sm_factor = np.array([0.1 ,0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1])


d2m = np.zeros((num, num))
d2m[0, 0] = 2
d2m[0, 1] = -5
d2m[0, 2] = 4
d2m[0, 3] = -1

for k in range(1, num-1):
    d2m[k, k-1] = 1
    d2m[k, k] = -2
    d2m[k, k+1] = 1

d2m[num-1, num-4] = -1
d2m[num-1, num-3] = 4
d2m[num-1, num-2] = -5
d2m[num-1, num-1] = 2

x_smf  = 0
for i in range(len(sm_factor)):
    x_smf = x_smf + sm_factor[i] * (d2m @ (A[i, :]).T).T @ (d2m @ (A[i, :]).T)

x_smf
# 324.0
```

Comment: For a start `d2m[0, 0:4] = [2,-5,4,-1]`

Comment: `(((d2m @ A.T) * (d2m @ A.T)).sum(0) * sm_factor).sum()`, if you have a different *sm_factor* for every iteration. Otherwise you can replace *sm_factor* with `.1`.

Comment: For larger arrays save `a = d2m @ A.T` to avoid redundant computations: `((a * a).sum(0) * .1).sum()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid loops for both `d2m` matrix creation and `x_smf` vector computation using [sps.diags](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.diags.html) for the creation of a sparse tridiagonal matrix that you can cast to array to be able to edit the first and last lines. Your code will look like this (note that the result of `diags` in line 10 has been cast to a dense ndarray using [scipy.sparse.dia_matrix.toarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.dia_matrix.toarray.html) method):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sps

# Dense tridiagonal matrix
d2m = sps.diags([1, -2, 1], [-1, 0, 1], shape=(num, num)).toarray() # cast to array
# First line boundary conditions
d2m[0, 0] = 2
d2m[0, 1] = -5
d2m[0, 2] = 4
d2m[0, 3] = -1
# Last line boundary conditions
d2m[num-1, num-4] = -1
d2m[num-1, num-3] = 4
d2m[num-1, num-2] = -5
d2m[num-1, num-1] = 2
```

The solution proposed by [Valdi_Bo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70817137/6683322) enables you to remove the second FOR loop:

```
x_smf = np.sum(sm_factor * np.square(d2m @ A.T).sum(axis=0))
```

However, I want to attract your attention on the fact that the `x_smf` matrix is sparse and storing it as a dense ndarray is bad for both computation time and memory storage. Instead of casting to dense ndarray, I advise you to cast to a [sparse matrix format](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html). For example [lil_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.lil_matrix), which is a list of lists sparse matrix format, using tolil() method instead of toarray():

```
# Sparse tridiagonal matrix
d2m_s = sps.diags([1, -2, 1], [-1, 0, 1], shape=(num, num)).tolil() # cast to lil
```

Here is a script that compares the three implementations on a bigger case `num=4000` (for `num=5` all give `324`). For this size, I am already seeing benefits of using sparse matrix, here is the whole script (the first lines are a generalisation of the code for `num` different from `5`):

```
from time import time
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sps

num = 4000

A = np.concatenate([np.arange(1, (num-2)*num+1).reshape(num, num-2), np.repeat([[4, 5]], num, axis=0)], axis=1)
sm_factor = 0.1*np.ones(num)

########## DENSE matrix + FOR loop ##########

d2m = sps.diags([1, -2, 1], [-1, 0, 1], shape=(num, num)).toarray() # cast to array
# First line boundary conditions
d2m[0, 0] = 2
d2m[0, 1] = -5
d2m[0, 2] = 4
d2m[0, 3] = -1
# Last line boundary conditions
d2m[num-1, num-4] = -1
d2m[num-1, num-3] = 4
d2m[num-1, num-2] = -5
d2m[num-1, num-1] = 2

# FOR loop version
t_start = time()
x_smf  = 0
for i in range(len(sm_factor)):
    x_smf = x_smf + sm_factor[i] * (d2m @ (A[i, :]).T).T @ (d2m @ (A[i, :]).T)
print(f'FOR loop version time:           {time()-t_start}s')
print(f'FOR loop version value:          {x_smf}\n')

########## DENSE matrix + VECTORIZED ##########

t_start = time()
x_smf_v = np.sum(sm_factor * np.square(d2m @ A.T).sum(axis=0))
print(f'VECTORIZED version time:         {time()-t_start}s')
print(f'VECTORIZED version value:        {x_smf_v}\n')

########## SPARSE matrix + VECTORIZED ##########

d2m_s = sps.diags([1, -2, 1], [-1, 0, 1], shape=(num, num)).tolil() # cast to lil
# First line boundary conditions
d2m_s[0, 0] = 2
d2m_s[0, 1] = -5
d2m_s[0, 2] = 4
d2m_s[0, 3] = -1
# Last line boundary conditions
d2m_s[num-1, num-4] = -1
d2m_s[num-1, num-3] = 4
d2m_s[num-1, num-2] = -5
d2m_s[num-1, num-1] = 2

t_start = time()
x_smf_s = np.sum(sm_factor * np.square(d2m_s @ A.T).sum(axis=0))
print(f'SPARSE+VECTORIZED version time:  {time()-t_start}s')
print(f'SPARSE+VECTORIZED version value: {x_smf_s}\n')
```

Here is what I get when running the code:

```
FOR loop version time:           25.878241777420044s
FOR loop version value:          3.752317536763356e+17

VECTORIZED version time:         1.0873610973358154s
VECTORIZED version value:        3.752317536763356e+17

SPARSE+VECTORIZED version time:  0.37279224395751953s
SPARSE+VECTORIZED version value: 3.752317536763356e+17
```

As you can see the use of a sparse matrix makes you win another factor 3 on computation time and doesn't require you to adapt the code coming afterwards. It is also a good strategy to test the various scipy implementations of sparse matrices (tocsc(), tocsr(), todok() etc.), some may be more adapted to your case.

Comment: Indeed using the sparse approach makes a difference

Answer (score 1):

After some research and printout of intermediate results of your loop,
I found the solution:

```
x_smf = np.sum(sm_factor * np.square(d2m @ A.T).sum(axis=0))
```

The result is:

```
324.0
```

By the way: Creation of *dm2* can be shortened to:

```
d2m = np.zeros((num, num), dtype='int')
d2m[0, :4] = [ 2, -5,  4, -1]
for k in range(1, num-1):
    d2m[k, k-1:k+2] = [ 1, -2,  1]
d2m[-1, -4:] = [-1, 4, -5, 2]
```

Comment: Pretty sure you don't need the loop if you pay attention to the indices

Comment: @ Valdi_Bo the last line should be  d2m[num-1, -4:] = [-1, 4, -5, 2]. index is -4: not 1:

Comment: You're right. I changed also the way how the first index is expressed.